# Running each_with_index on one line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to make a helper that ouputs the equivalent of

```
<%= localed_data.header.states.each_with_index do |f, i|  %>
    <%= "data-#{i}=#{f}" %>
<%- end -%>
```

(three data-attributes from an array)

When writing a helper, I need it to go on the last line. I tried this but it outputs nothing for some reason.

```
<%= localed_data.header.states.each_with_index { |f, i| "data-#{i}=#{f}"} %>
```

What's wrong with my code or what is a better way to keep an output an array from a helper?

Comment: What you want is very confusing...  Why you are trying the second approach? Where is your helper code ?

Comment: Well for starters in very basic terms `<%=` means render visually where as `<%` (no `=`) means interpret but do not visually render the return. Secondly `each` will always return the receiver regardless of the block so this will not have the impact you are hoping for either. As @Nermin said `#map` is probably your best bet here.

Comment: Are you trying to build HTML5 data-attributes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `map` instead of `each`, to output in single line

```
<%= localed_data.header.states.map.with_index { |f, i| "data-#{i}=#{f} "}.join %>
```